# Firefox (v23) bug when appending image to dom after delay (JS Fiddle included)

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

The following code in firefox causes an the image to NOT be displayed in correct location. (It should be in center of video). It works fine in chrome and other browsers. It also works  if the image is not appended to DOM but loads initially OR if the window is re-sized after page load.

This only happens in firefox and I cannot come up with a solution. (NOTE: we need to append the images in javascript because it is a result of an API call that we want to do client side and NOT server side)

JS Fiddle Broken: http://jsfiddle.net/B6eYm/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a.video_link
{
    position:relative;
}

img
{
    width: 100%;
}

img.videoPlay
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    display:none;
}

.video-main
{
    width: 49.16%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Firefox Bug</h1>

<div class="video-main">
    <a class="video_link" data-video-id="2621309976001" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img class="videoPlay" src="http://media.democratandchronicle.com/sites/default/files/icon-videoPlay-wide.png"/>
    </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        var video_id = '2621309976001';
        var video_still = 'http://bcdownload.gannett.edgesuite.net/rochester/36517057001/201308/796/36517057001_2637049604001_video-still-for-video-2632520077001.jpg?pubId=36517057001';
        $("a[data-video-id='" + video_id + "']").append('<img src="'+video_still+'" />').find('.videoPlay').show();
    }, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Js Fiddle Working: http://jsfiddle.net/N9mHe/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a.video_link
{
    position:relative;
}

img
{
    width: 100%;
}

img.videoPlay
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    display:none;
}

.video-main
{
    width: 49.16%;
    display: block;
    float: left
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Firefox Bug</h1>

<div class="video-main">
    <a class="video_link" data-video-id="" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <img style="display: inline;" class="videoPlay" src="http://media.democratandchronicle.com/sites/default/files/icon-videoPlay-wide.png"/>
    <img src="http://bcdownload.gannett.edgesuite.net/rochester/36517057001/201308/796/36517057001_2637049604001_video-still-for-video-2632520077001.jpg?pubId=36517057001" />
    </a>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the setTimeout for?

Comment: Curiously enough, when opening and closing firebug, the play button positions itself correctly.  It must be a bug with firefox.

Comment: Looks like a bug alright.

Comment: the setTimeout is to simulate an API call. I didn't want to include the api call in the example to add unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add `display:block` to your `a.video_link` it should work properly:

http://jsfiddle.net/B6eYm/1/

Comment: Thank you very much! I spent 1 hour trying to figure this out!

Comment: Out of curiosity how does this fix it? I know that an a tag is inline, but how does block all of a sudden make it work?

Comment: I think as it was inline it never expands properly when you put an image inside it, by making it block or inline-block it just changes the rendering so it covers the whole image.  If you inspect the element of the anchor when it's inline, you will see it is down near the bottom of the new image (which is why your play image was so low)